# Issue with carrying out a difference-in-differences analysis using PISA data and R software

Tags: pisa

I am in the process of carrying out a difference-in-differences analysis using 2000-2018 PISA (Program for International Student Assessment)data. One of the issues that I have is that data analysis function must take into account the replicate weights and  plausible values of achievement scores in the calculation of point estimates and standard errors of means, standard deviations, regression coefficients, and frequency tables. Packages like "instvy" (see link below) have been developed to facilitate analysis with PISA data (accounting for replicate weights and plausible values to calculate point estimates). However, this package has not been extended to difference-in-differences analysis.

I am trying to use R-software to carry out the analysis. However, I cannot find any literature to help guide me as I carry out this analysis.

Does anyone have experience with carrying out difference-in-differences using PISA data? IS there a sample code somewhere that I have not come across?

I have look for resources, but have not come across anything specific to difference-in-differences and PISA.